# Какие есть IDE для работы непосредственно на сервере?

Tags: ssh, ide

Разрабатываю сайты сразу на сервере через SSH. На локальном компьютере ничего не устанавливаю. Мне так удобно, особенно когда работать приходится на разных компьютерах. Использую пока редактор Notepad++. Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли возможность в таком режиме использовать более продвинутые редакторы типа phpstorm, sublime и т.д. чтобы было видно сразу все папки и файлы проекта и при сохранении сохранялись файлы по SSH на сервере?

Comment: https://litl-admin.ru/fajlovye-sistemy/kak-k-windows-podklyuchit-fajlovuyu-sistemu-udalyonnogo-linux-servera-po-ssh.html

Comment: vscode + remote ssh https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/07/25/remote-ssh